# Can we undelete this answer to the heat wave / fan question?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

There's a question posted earlier today that described a situation where the OP is conflicted about getting their fan back from their colleagues, due to the extremely hot weather that they are all experiencing - here's the link:

[Reclaiming my desk fan when the office I lent it to is also really hot](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/17130/reclaiming-my-desk-fan-when-the-office-i-lent-it-to-is-also-really-hot)

My answer to their question, which agrees with an original answer and offers an alternative solution - purchasing a cooling vest - is a good one, imho, as I don't know how anything else but an alternative solution will do, in this unfortunate situation, especially since the OP has requested that no legal remedies be suggested and mentioned that no additional electronic devices would be allowed in the workplace.

Here was my answer, for those of you who don't have enough rep to see
deleted content:

> I agree with Daniel's answer that you would risk emphasizing your
>   privilege over the people in the marketing department, so the answer
>   to your question would be to simply not bring it up.
>
> However, you had mentioned at the end of your question that you'd be
>   willing to seek other solutions, so here's one:
>
> Consider buying a **cooling vest**, which is not an electronic device;
>   it's unpowered, so your boss could allow for this in the office - the
>   vests are designed for people who work in very hot temperatures, e.g.
>   people who work in a hot office, construction workers, dog walkers,
>   people who work in oil fields, athletes, etc.  It keeps you cool for
>   about 2.5 hours, but if you have a freezer at your office, you can
>   store additional cooling packs in the freezer and then use them later
>   in the day.  You can Google search or go on Amazon to look for a
>   cooling vest, sometimes also known as an ice vest.
>
> It's interesting to note that your willingness to seek an alternative
>   solution, rather than demanding that the marketing department return
>   your fan during this unfortunate heat wave, highlights several key
>   interpersonal skills that you're using:
>
> - conflict management
> - empathy
> - teamwork
> - listening

I then showed a couple photos of cooling vests.

Other answers are suggesting forceful action and legal remedies - which is what the OP doesn't want - and another answer suggests getting blindfolds for the office windows, which actually aligns with my goal of seeking an alternative solution, yet those answers are not deleted.

Can I get my answer undeleted?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that your answer doesn't actually offer an interpersonal solution, which is what this site is all about. So while yes, the cooling vest would solve the immediate "I am too warm" part of things, that's an intrapersonal solution as it doesn't actually respond to the "I need to get the fan back, and that means dealing with the people who have the fan" part.

Since this is an Interpersonal Skills site, we want answers to focus on that aspect of things. Many things here could potentially be solved with solutions that are not interpersonal solutions, but that's not what we are specifically here for.

Comment: Thanks Ash, it's certainly an interpersonal solution, I believe - see the skills listed in my answer that the OP would be using.  I think we need to be careful not to reduce the set of interpersonal skills to a direct conversation / confrontation - the interpersonal skill set is much broader.  Otherwise, this Stack Exchange should be more narrowly defined as Communications Stack Exchange.

Comment: Also, the OP had mentioned that if they feel they'd make enemies, then they are prepared to handle the heat wave themselves and seek other solutions.  The solution I offer is both a simple life-hack and an interpersonal solution.

Comment: @JalapenoNachos If you cut out the section describing cooling vests, your answer turns into "I agree with Daniel's answer. You should seek an alternative. This shows skills 1, 2, and 3." This seems more like a comment than a standalone answer, especially since the skills part reads like a side note right now.

Comment: @EmC why would I cut out the section describing cooling vests?

Comment: @JalapenoNachos Well, giving alternative ways to cool is off topic (we aren't Life hacks SE) - so the vest part should be the side note, rather than the other way around. For example, look at Jon's answer, he lists some alternatives to explore but still focuses on the interpersonal skills involved.

Comment: @EmC an alternative solution is actually pretty central to the OP's question, not merely a side-note.  Moreover, if we do want to compare to Jon's answer, Jon suggests getting blinds for the office, which is an *alternative solution* and also his suggestion of getting more fans goes against the OP's request for no additional electronic devices.

Comment: @JalapenoNachos Hm I may not be explaining properly, I mean that it's ok to mention an alternate, but your answer should still be able to stand on its own as an IPS answer regardless of whether that alternate is "buy a vest" or "get blinds" or something else

Answer (score -1):

You also missed the big note on the bottom of the original question (or it was not there when you posted) but:

**"Note that I'm not looking for legal remedies to the situation or outside remedies like "manage to somehow sneak in another fan""**

I think your suggestion falls very clearly to the outside remedies and thus is specifically what OP didnt want.

Comment: The OP very clearly said that they were prepared to deal with the heat and seek alternative solutions, written in boldface - go and read the original question, unedited.

Comment: If that was the case I apologize, I didn't bother to check exact time on edits and the answer. Though even if it had merit at the time of posting I don't believe it should be undeleted now as now it would fall outside of what the question is looking for. Feel free to post another answer that answers the question in its current state.

Comment: Ok no worries - thanks.  Yeah, it's a tough question with rigid constraints; I'm afraid I don't have a better answer than my current deleted one.

Comment: @JalapenoNachos Thats a bit my fault. I wanted to ask this here, but I also knew that I had to make the advice given really narrow for it not to get closed, hence the constraints.

Comment: @Magisch no worries - thanks :)